# Listen for line-changed event on custom eclipse editor

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, editor, listener

I create a custom eclipse editor like that:

```
public class MyEditor extends AbstractDecoratedTextEditor {
```

And I want to add a listener thats execute every time I change the line or change the cursor place.

Thanks.

Comment: add an event listener to this class ...
Mouse and keyboard

Comment: Its work, I added the mouse and keyboard listener using the code below:
getSourceViewer().getTextWidget().addMouseListener(mouseListener);
getSourceViewer().getTextWidget().addKeyListener(keyListener);

Comment: For what purpose? What problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: When the line changed, I need to know the number...
Its works using mouse and keyboard to change the line, but doesnt work when the line changed using some function like when breakpoint select the line. The method addCaretListener give-me the old number of line, not the current line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `StyledText` `addCaretListener` to listen for movements of the caret.

In your `MyEditor` class use:

```
StyledText styledText = (StyledText)getAdapter(Control.class);

styledText.addCaretListener(listener);
```

Comment: When I get the selected line using selectionProvider.getSelection() on the method addCaretListener, I had the old number of line, not the current line selected.

Comment: The `CaretEvent` `caretOffset` field contains the new caret position.